# OpenTBS - Repeating a block of data from multiple MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, opentbs

I'm trying to repeat a set of data from MySQL record set and repeat it for each query using OpenTBS.

Here is my template
[image]

For one query, I can merge data with $TBS->Show() method. but I want to execute multiple queries and for each query the data should be repeated on a new page in the same document and in the same format as shown.

I know that TBS blocks will be used but I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.